# count the number of dictionaries in a string python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new to Python and coding in general. my question is how to find the numbers of  dictionaries in a this string.
This is a file called dataHistory.json

```
{
"lists": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "name": "B"
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "name": "C"
        },
        {
            "number": 4,
            "name": "D"
        },
        {
            "number": 5,
            "name": "E"
        },
        {
            "number": 6,
            "name": "F"
        },
        {
            "number": 7,
            "name": "G"
        },
        {
            "number": 8,
            "name": "H"
        },
        {
            "number": 9,
            "name": "I"
        },

    ]
}
```

The result I want to get is a number to print 9

also as a reminder dataHistory.json will add in more dictionaries.

My Code I started.

```
    def _get_data_history(self):
        theHistory = open(self.history_path)
        holdHistory = json.load(theHistory)
        theHistory.close()
        return holdHistory

theDataHistory = obj._get_data_history()
print theDataHistory['RestaurantsHistory'] # stuck here
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does this string `RestaurantsHistory` come from? It's not in the JSON file.

Comment: The dictionaries are in `lists`, so `print len(theDataHistory['lists'])` should do it.

Comment: I've added an answer, but then I've realized, that I misinterpreted your question, asking about the number of `dict`s not the number 9 in one of the `dict`. So I've deleted the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys! soo fast! i frogot to replace RestaurantsHistory. sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this, but no idea where 'RestaurantsHistory' comes from:

```
print len(theDataHistory['RestaurantsHistory']['lists'])
```

otherwise this:

```
print len(theDataHistory['lists'])
```

Comment: Actually, in his example he uses `lists` instead of `list`. Beside this typo, your solution works.

Comment: I also use `lists`, see my answer again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list (or tuple, set, dictionary, string, or many other possibilities) of anything (even a mixture of things), `len(the_list)` gives the number of elements. `len` is short for length.

Your sample JSON results in a dictionary with one key `"lists"`. You can get to the value with `json_data["lists"]` and the number of elements will thus be `len(json_data["lists"])`. Here `json_data` is either `theDataHistory` or `theDataHistory['RestaurantsHistory']`, it's not clear what happened at the end of your code since there's no `RestaurantsHistory` in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

**len(s)**

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may
>   be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a
>   collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

[ref doc.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)

```
dict = {'lists':[{'number':1,'name':'A'},
                 {'number':2,'name':'B'},
                 {'number':3,'name':'C'}]
       }
print len(dict) # outputs 1
print len(dict['lists']) # outputs 3
print len(dict['lists'][0]) # output 2
```